# Groovy compilation using groovyc uses jvm process?

Tags: groovy, compilation

While looking at groovy compilation process using goovyc I observed that the groovc tool shipped with groovy is a script which internally runs a java main class  (org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter).
So does this mean that when using groovc ,the  groovy compilation itself occurs in a jvm process where it parses the source files and then converts them in to byte codes, all this happening using a jvm process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The same is true for javac. In fact, the majority of programming languages has the main compiler written in the language itself. This practice is known as [bootstrapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28compilers%29).

Comment: In fact, many programs written in Java show up as java.exe in your OS's process list. Kind of makes it difficult to tell which process to kill if one misbehaves.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question, but I believe the answer is yes.  Groovy is compiled to bytecode by a java process.